# How can I fetch data from the host URL in getStaticPaths in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a Next.js app that uses a serverless function to fetch data from its host. The host URL is stored in a `.env` file and is set to `http://localhost:3000/api/data` for dev and `https://productionurl.com/api/data` for production.

However, for testing purposes, I have hosted the app on Vercel, and the testing URL will be randomly generated, such as `https://randomvercelurl_abcd1234.com/api/data`.

I can use `ctx` or `req` to get the host URL in the `getServerSideProps` method, as shown in the example code below:

```
export async function getServerSideProps({query, req}){
    const API_URL = req.protocol + req.headers.host + "/api/data"
    const res = await axios.get(API_URL)
 ...
}
```

The problem arises in the `getStaticPaths` method, where I need to fetch data to generate dynamic routes. I don't have any way to get the host URL in this method, as demonstrated in the following example code:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const host = ???
    const res = await fetch(`${host}/api/data`)
    const posts = await res.json()

    const paths = posts.map((post) => ({
        params: { id: post.id },
    }))

    return { paths, fallback: false }
}
```

How can I access the host URL in the `getStaticPaths` method to fetch data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot get a `ctx` with `host` like in `getServerSideProps` because [`getStaticPaths`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths) runs at build time. This means the URL from which you want to fetch data should exist when calling `npm run build` and should be fully known, either written directly in the code or through an environment variable.

> `getStaticPaths` will only run during build in production, it will not be called during runtime.

The solution in your case is to add the randomly generated URL into your environment variable on Vercel, or wherever you host your app. You may also wanna read [when should I use getStaticPaths.](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths#when-should-i-use-getstaticpaths)